# Retrieve data from header individually in PHP

Tags: php

I have this url
`/Home/GetAll?{"offset":0,"rowNumber":5,"sortExpression":"ID","sortOrder":"ASC","pageNumber":1}`

How do I get the value of offset and other stuff individually in php?

Comment: use get and json_decode() in php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting JSON Object by calling a URL with parameters in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262732/getting-json-object-by-calling-a-url-with-parameters-in-php)

Comment: Have you tried any thing???

Comment: Can't use json_decode because my Get is not in string.

Comment: The shown string is _not_ a URL.

Comment: This is the url `http://localhost:70/appanalytic_task12/Home/GetAll?{%22offset%22:0,%22rowNumber%22:5,%22sortExpression%22:%22ID%22,%22sortOrder%22:%22ASC%22,%22pageNumber%22:1}`

Comment: `explode` the result with `?` and store the value as json string and parse it

Comment: What does it mean "my Get is not in string"?

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach($_REQUEST as $key=>$val){
            $result=json_decode($key);
            $offset=$result->offset;
            echo $offset;
        }
```

Comment: Although this might solve the problem, a good answer requires to explain what the code is doing and why it is working.